# Can the word "orbital" mean expensive/high?

Tags: meaning

I have heard someone say "As a consultant, Dave can charge orbital fees, so we would rather have you do it."

I tried to look up "orbital" but did not find what I was expecting.

Comment: I suspect you heard someone say "exorbitant fees", which would indeed mean unreasonably high fees.

Comment: If OP himself didn't mishear, it's a racing cert the person he heard did. I'm voting to close.

Comment: "The OP must have heard it wrong" is the _only_ explanation?

Comment: Ding ding ding! Ring the eggcorn bell! Here's another example from SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056752/advice-on-doing-business-with-non-programmers

Comment: And I can readily interpret it as meaning higher than sky-high.

Comment: @Hugo Nice insight. Surprising, I didn't think of it. That way, '*orbital* fees' could perhaps mean exorbitant.

Comment: @Job I suspect the certain Dave is a rocket scientist, or the speaker certainly is.

Answer (score 7):

As Bjorn points out, "orbital" is phonetically similar to "exorbitant".  Indeed, they share the same etymological root.

In addition to the similarity of sound, I suspect that someone might think of the fact that objects in orbit are very high up, or that getting an object into orbit requires accelerating it to a very high speed ("orbital speeds").  So if someone thought they heard "orbital fees" they could reasonably infer a metaphorical use that could fit in the context.

Comment: Substituting a plausible, but wrong word in this way is called an eggcorn.

Comment: This must be it. While it is fun to invent new words, I would stick to the ones that already exist.

Comment: It's also conceptually (kind of) similar to astronomical, which would fit in context.

Comment: @Job They weren't inventing a new word; they were exaggerating for effect.

Answer (score 3):

It's obviously a bit of *[hyperbole](http://www.wordnik.com/words/hyperbole)*.

A satellite requires a certain combination of *altitude* and *velocity* to [orbit around the earth](http://science.howstuffworks.com/satellite3.htm).

As [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_space) notes:

> The minimum altitude for a stable orbit around Earth (that is, one
>   without significant atmospheric drag) is around 350 kilometres (220
>   mi) above sea level.

This is very high indeed; by contrast, Mt Everest is a mere 8840 meters (5.5 mi) high.

So *orbital fees* are more than sky-high; after all, NASA considers anyone who travels above 80 km (50 mi) an *astronaut*.

Comment: -1 for atempting to justify a mishearing

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh, that's harsh; I'd certainly recognize and understand [hyperbole](http://www.wordnik.com/words/hyperbole) like "orbital fees" if I heard it.

Comment: I regard it as a plausible attempt at hyperbole. The tech world is full of wits and wordplayers. I work with some of them. But I do think, following on from James McLeod's answer, that stratospheric, thermospheric, or exospheric would be more correct hyperbolic escalations (in increasing levels of hyperbole).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: whether it is an eggcorn on anybodies part or not, it still works. After 'orbital' comes 'astronomical', then 'galactic', then ... 'limits of the visible universe' just doesn't have the right punch.

Comment: @JonathanVM Very true; but how often is hyperbole governed by logic?

Comment: Now I want to go watch "Powers of Ten"

Answer (score 2):

The more common altitude-related idiom for "sky high" is stratospheric. I've never heard "orbital" used in this way, and it seems wrong - the primary characteristic of something which is orbital is that it orbits something, not that it is high above the surface.